# jquery width get 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, width

jquery function width() always return 0. Here is my layout

```
<div class="entity" id="id-@user.id">
   <div class="inactive">
      <div class="touch-header">                                               
         <div>
            <small>@user.name<br>@user.surname</small>
         </div>

         <div role="button" data-toggle="modal" id="home_office_id-@user.id" class="home_office_log pull-right" style="margin-top: -2.2%;text-align:center; margin-right: 2px;opacity: 0.8;width: 50px; height: 50px;position: absolute; margin-left: 4.9%;z-index: 1;">
           ...
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then I have javascript code where I want to move content of tags < small> < /small> via animate method to the mid of div class="entity"

```
var lab = $('div.entity#id-' + userId).children().
        children().children().children('small');                         
lab.css('position', 'relative').animate({
    left: $('.entity#id-'+userId).width() - lab.width() / 2 - 15
}, 500);
```

But functions width() in both case returns 0. What can I do?

Comment: `.children().children().children().children('small');` -- `.find("small")`

Comment: You have to show the generated HTML, I'm assuming `@user-id` gets replaced, because jQuery tell me `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div.entity#id-@user.id `

Comment: @JuanMendes - this probably is asp.net MVC razor code

Comment: yes, it is generated from java framework. Just put there any number, it does not change anything. And use same number for variable userId

Comment: @ParvSharma I don't care what server side framework it is. For the question to be clear, you should show the actual HTML that the browser sees. Along with telling us what `userId` is. The better you make your questions, the more likely that someone will help, if we have to keep digging, we'll stop looking, as I just did

Comment: Sorry, hope this helps. http://paste2.org/8yPXNEBh

Comment: Sometimes, jQuery will try and grab the width of an element before it's finished loading it's contents. Moreso happens with images, but potentially your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it was all about generating another page as a clone to different tab, so even the layout was generetad just once, the jquery objects were created twice into DOM. And that selector returned 2 objects, but just one of them had set width attribute properly. Anyway thanks for responses especialy @Juan

Answer (score -2):

Try `innerWidth` or `outerWidth`, they actually compute the value, `width` AFAIK returns only the one from CSS.

Comment: Answers that are saying "try this" should be a comment. If you know that's the problem, then it should be an answer. `$.width` does not return the value set in CSS, it uses the computed style